# Unir dos imágenes en Laravel

Tags: laravel, imagen, gd

Estoy intentando unir dos imágenes pero no logro conseguirlo.

La idea es que el usuario suba su foto en **el registro** del sistema, y que al registrarse le llegue una imagen en su email en formato story (1080 x 1920). Para ello tengo guardado en el servidor una imagen que es un marco para la foto del usuario. Entonces, la idea es unir esta imagen PNG del marco, con la foto que suba el usuario. (Lo ideal sería que la imagen que suba el usuario se pueda recortar al tamaño de la story y de forma centrada, para que sea simplemente poner una imagen encima de la otra).

Encontré esta librería [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/introduction) pero no logro hacerla funcionar, y quisiera de su ayuda para lograrlo!

Acá coloco el código que estoy utilizando dentro del RegisterController.php:

```
...
use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    use RegistersUsers;
    private $imageManager;

    public function __construct(ImageManager $imageManager)
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
        $this->imageManager = $imageManager;
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        
        $request = app('request');

        if( $request->hasfile('photo') ){
            $fileUpload = Storage::disk('public') -> put('img/students', $request -> file("photo"));

            $img_photo = public_path() . '/' . $fileUpload;
            $img_border = $data['facu'];

            $img_canvas = $this -> imageManager -> canvas(1080,1920);

            $img_canvas->insert(Image::make($img_photo), 'top-left'); 
            $img_canvas->save(public_path()."/img/students/marcos/".$id_left."_vs_".$id_right.".jpg", 100);

            $img_canvas->insert($this->imageManager->make($img_border), 'top-left');
            $img_canvas->insert($this->imageManager->make($img_photo), 'top-left');

            $img_canvas->save(public_path()."/img/students/marcos/".$id_left."_vs_".$id_right.".jpg", 100);

        }

        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'years' => $data['years'],
            'category' => $data['category'],
            'city' => $data['city'],
            'province' => $data['province'],
            'country' => $data['country'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'type' => 2
        ]);

    }
}
```